# Show content if child of a specific page

Tags: php, wordpress, parent, if-statement

I am building a website in WordPress and have a set of photos that display along the top of the page (in the background) and have them to where the set of photos can change depending on where the visitor is on the website. For example, if they are looking at the FAQ page, then photos pertaining to asking questions are shown. If they are looking at the news page, then photos pertaining to news are shown. The code I have works great, however, I'd like to now show photos based on the parent of the page they are on; for instance, if they are looking at a child page under a parent.

Here's my code as it stands now:

`<?php if ( is_front_page() ) { include'media/home.php'; }
    elseif ( is_404() ) { include'media/404s.php'; }
    elseif ( is_page('news') ) { include'media/home.php'; }
    elseif ( is_page('faqs') ) { include'media/faqs.php'; }
    elseif ( is_category('africa-2') ) { include'media/faqs.php'; }
    else { include'media/general.php'; }
?>`

How can I tell WordPress, I want it to show a certain php file if it is a parent page and all of it's children?

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the loop you can just use

```
if( is_page('faqs') && $post->post_parent ){
  //include template here
}
```

If you're outside the loop you'll need to include global $post before the conditional.

```
global $post
```

You can reference this link http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#Testing_for_sub-Pages